# inner working of 'fixed': working on memory location or object?

Tags: c#, arrays, fixed, unsafe

In managed/unmanaged array interoperability, I have a case of not having the usual

```
fixed (byte* data = new byte[length])
{
    // work with the array
}
```

but rather, I want to pin an array where I only get a reference, like this:

```
IntPtr dataPtr = camera.Image2d.GetDataBuffer();
fixed (byte* data = (byte *)dataPtr)
{
   // work with the array
}
```

1) From my understanding, the bottom code should also work, since 'fixed' will pin a memory location low level in the memory manager, and not care about any objects pointing to it? (Meaning, I do not have the "root"/a direct pointer - even though there probably is not any such concept.)

One additional question:

2) The requirement to use 'fixed' comes from the CLR memory manager running concurrently to any executed code, thus it could move arrays at any time?

Comment: The `fixed` part may just work after you solve the typecasting.

Comment: The GC can't move memory around, only objects. If `GetDataBuffer` returns an `IntPtr`, the pointer should already point to memory that contains a pinned object (or to unmanaged memory). It doesn't make a lot of sense to return a pointer to memory with an unpinned object.

Comment: This looks very dubious to me. Where is the IntPtr coming from? Is it returned from something via P/Invoke? It could be pointing to some unmanaged memory, so pinning it will have zero effect. If it is pointing to some managed object, why is it an IntPtr rather than the actual reference?

Comment: Hmm, I thought the compiler prevents you from fixing local variables are there is no point. But I agree with @MatthewWatson

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think my understanding of IntPtr being already unmanaged was lacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)  the second one does not seem proper as using the `fixed` keyword you are trying to pin the pointer, not the actual object. And `IntPtr` is not even (afaik) a managed pointer, rather an unmanaged one.

2) `fixed` creates a pointer to the specified managed variable; and without pinning, GC may relocate the variable to another memory location, thus pointer will become useless.

from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx):

> The fixed statement sets a pointer to a managed variable and "pins"
>   that variable during the execution of the statement. Without fixed,
>   pointers to movable managed variables would be of little use since
>   garbage collection could relocate the variables unpredictably. The C#
>   compiler only lets you assign a pointer to a managed variable in a
>   fixed statement.